# How do I configure two email accounts inside one Outlook profile in 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I'm trying to configure two email accounts inside one outlook profile in 2007.  I did it before, but this time I'm getting an error when I try to add second account.

Error:

> This account or directory type is already exists and cannot be specified twice

I took one account as Exchange, the other one is POP email.

What I did:

1. Created a new profile. Only one profile is there named as Outlook. I configured my email id `ashish.f@concerto.com`. It is automatically added as Microsoft Exchange and is working fine.
2. Now I need to add my second id `ashish.f@syne.com` which is from another client. I go to mail setup > Email-accounts and click on New rather than select Microsoft exchange, which is previously configured and select the change option. I choose the first option pop3, imap.. > and enter my new id details. Here I got the error "these account or directory already exist."

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

- In Outlook, go to *Tools > Options > Mail Setup > Email Accounts*
- Select your already configured first email account and choose *Change*.
- Select *Change* then *More Settings*.
- Go to *Advanced* (Open these addtional mailboxes) and add the other mailbox.

Comment: When i try to add my name into `mailbox` getting error :
`the name cannot be resolved. the name can not be match to name in the address list`

Comment: Can the second account be added first then? Check the server and ensure the account exists and the user account has permissions to open it.

Comment: both account from different servers :(
one is from client server other is from my company server.
I HAVE CONFIGURE CLIENT ACCOUNT FIRST NOW OPEN PROFILE AS A MICROSOFT EXCHANGE. NOW OPEN EMAIL ACCOUNT OPTION ADD TRY TO ADD NEW EMAIL POP ID AS MY SECOND COMPANY ACCOUNT IS IT OK?

Comment: Ok so instad of add another email box you need to confure a differnt server type and server will change my answer then.

Comment: please help accordingly

Comment: Before I write the answer in your question explain the type of email you are trying to add smtp, pop, or exchange. Also how do you authenticate to both accounts etc.. Once I have that i'll write up your answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3227/discussion-between-ashuthinks-and-dc5553)

Comment: please help accordingly

Comment: @ashuthinks Comments are not chat. Please don't ping the person answering with "please help accordingly" all the time, and don't write in all caps. Thank you.

Comment: @slhck i'm not able to add second account yet :(
what i did till now:
1.created a new profile only one profile is there named as `outlook`
configure my email id `ashish.f@concerto.com` it is automatically added as `Microsoft Exchange` working fine
2.Now i need to add my 2nd id `ashish.f@syne.com` which is from other client.
I go to mail setup > Email-accounts clicked on `New` rather than `select Microsoft exchange which is previously configure and select change option`.
Choose 1st option pop3,imap.. > enter my new id details.
here got error `these account or directory already exist` plz help?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Outlook's *Tools » Account settings*. Click *New* then just add your next mail account.